# Regex - Pattern Matching & Replace

Tags: regex

Text is: "R1 AND R24 OR R456'

I want to write a pattern that can find R and the numbers (only numbers) following it.
So the matches will be: R1, R24, R456.

How can I write appropriate regex?

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
\bR\d+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u549)

`\b` is a anchor for a word boundary, that means here there can be no word character (letter, number and _) before the `R`

`\d` is a digit

`+` one or more

If you want to replace the numbers you can do so (if your language supports lookbehinds)

```
(?<=\bR)\d+
```

See [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u54c)

For the correct syntax you need to tell us your language.

Answer (score 1):

## /R\d+/

- /.../ represents a regex (you don't type them in all languages)
- R represents a literal character R
- \d represents a digit
- \d+ represents "one or more" of whatever \d represents
- As other people pointed out, you can use \b to represent a "beginning of word" if you want to avoid matching the end of words like "thumb2"
- You can replace by doing something like s/R(\d+)/rev_\1/g to turn R132 into rev_132 all through the text
- The exact syntax of how to apply a regex varies from language to language: in Perl, you type something very like the /.../ syntax above. In other languages, you may use a string "R\d+" passed to a function. In some you need the slashes *inside* a string.
- You can test it online, eg: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm
- There are many online introductions, eg: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Yeah. The first pass had <!--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--> so I could give a 6 character answer, but I decided that if I was going to answer it at all, I should at least explain.

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be `\bR\d+`. To also capture the number you can use `\bR(\d+)`.

Answer (score 0):

The topic of your question says "Replace" but I can't find any points concerning possible replacement in your question.

The regex pattern `/R[0-9]+/` should work to find "R1", "R24", and "R456" in "R1 AND R24 OR R456".

To extract the numbers following the respective "R" you can add a group to the regex pattern: `/R([0-9]+)/`. Then you can just "match" the test string against the regex pattern and extract group 1 for each match:

```
Target String: R1 AND R24 OR R456
Regex Pattern: R([0-9]+)
"find next"; group(0): R1; group(1): 1
"find next"; group(0): R24; group(1): 24
"find next"; group(0): R456; group(1): 456
"find next"; null
```

Which programming language are you using? We could then provide an even concreter example.

Comment: I forgot to ask about replace. I need to get number part of the match. I suppose we can make groups in regex. How can I?

Comment: I edited my post to also address the extraction of the numbers. Maybe you tell us your programming language you are using the regex within. Then we could give a concrete example.